# Why is c++ prematurely destroying my string variable?

Tags: c++, debugging

This error is one of the most mysterious I've gotten in probably years. I've been trying things back and forth for hours now and can't understand it.

In the code below, I am trying to dynamically decide which derived class to instantiate. I use the function parameter `particle_type` in order to determine that.

But since

```
Particle p;
```

is not allowed, since you have to initialize references, I am trying to do it with a pointer as below.

```
Particle* p;
if (particle_type == "Featherr") { //This is never called because of the extra "r" I put, so ignore this block
        p = &FeatherParticle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);
}
else {
    p = &Particle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);
}

Particle particle1 = *p;
Particle particle2 = Particle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);

particles.push_back(particle1);
particles.push_back(particle2);
```

Now the particle2 is just me debugging, but it highlights this bug* very well. I put a breakpoint at `particles.push_back(particle1);` and found that the particle object stored by `particle1` was broken:

[image]

I do not understand why the string is set to "" here. I can only guess it has to do with the scoping, because if I set the string outside the else statement, it works. Which makes my jaw drop at how stupid this functionality is *which is why I think it may be a bug or near-bug functionality.

Comment: `pointer = &Object()` might work in Rust or Go, but it does not work in C++! Have you enabled all available compiler warnings?

Comment: Yes.  Namely, the object pointed to by p is destroyed instantly, even before exiting the `else {}` block.  The object pointed to by particle2 is also destroyed instantly and not valid.

Comment: Why are you messing with pointers? Why not just `particles.push_back(makeParticle(particle_type, particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale));`

Comment: The use of the constructor would be fine within the `push_back` parenthesis, a copy will be inserted in the array.

Comment: I guess you are using MSVC which allows taking address of rvalues for some reason  (instantly creating a dangling pointer)

Comment: I was going to say compile with `/permissive-` to disallow this, but it baffles me that this still compiles in that mode. Looks like you still need `/Za` to disable this extension. There are APIs out there that take things by pointer for performance where this is safe, but it's not a particularly common thing and hindsight is 20/20 on this being the default behaviour, but they're kind of stuck with it.

Comment: An anternative cannot be suggested without seeing how `particles` is defined

Comment: @MooingDuck I wanted to be able to choose whichever Particle to create, whether it be FeatherParticle or regular Particle or whichever. But your suggestion does make sense, it just isn't quite as elegant to read I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `p` to point at *temporary* objects that are destroyed immediately after the assignment, thus leaving `p` dangling.  You need to use `new` instead:

```cpp
Particle* p;
if (particle_type == "Featherr") { //This is never called because of the extra "r" I put, so ignore this block
    p = new FeatherParticle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);
}
else {
    p = new Particle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);
}
...
```

But then, you would be [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/) the object when assigning `*p` to `particle1`, so use a reference instead (or simply get rid of `particle1` since you don't need it):

```cpp
Particle &particle1 = *p;
```

But then, you are trying to push `Particle` *objects* into `particles`, not `Particle*` *pointers*.  So you would slice `particle1` anyway.  Polymorphism only works when using pointers/references, so you should be storing `Particle*` pointers (which means using `new` for `particle2` as well):

```cpp
std::vector<Particle*> particles;

...

Particle *p;
...
Particle *particle2 = new Particle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);

particles.push_back(p);
particles.push_back(particle2);
```

And don't forget to `delete` anything you `new` when you are done (and make sure `Particle` has a `virtual` destructor):

```cpp
for(size_t i = 0; i < particles.size(); ++i) {
    delete particles[i];
}
```

Or, in C++11 and later:

```cpp
for(auto *p : particles) {
    delete p;
}
```

But, it would be better to use `std::unique_ptr` to handle that `delete` for you automatically. Use `std::make_unique()` (C++14 and later), don't use `new` directly at all if you can avoid it:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Particle>> particles;

...

std::unique_ptr<Particle> p;
if (particle_type == "Featherr") { //This is never called because of the extra "r" I put, so ignore this block
    p = std::make_unique<FeatherParticle>(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);
    // or:
    // p.reset(new FeatherParticle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale));
}
else {
    p = std::make_unique<Particle>(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);
    // or:
    // p.reset(new Particle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale));
}

auto particle2 = std::make_unique<Particle>(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale);
// or:
// std::unique_ptr<Particle> particle2(new Particle(particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale));

particles.push_back(std::move(p));
particles.push_back(std::move(particle2));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little what you mean by "You are setting p to point at temporary objects that are destroyed immediately after the assignment"? What is the temporary object in this situation, and why is it temporary (I didn't want it to be immediately destroyed)

Comment: In `p = &FeatherParticle(...);`, `FeatherParticle(...)` creates a *temporary* unnamed (anonymous) `FeatherParticle` object, then `&` returns the memory address of that object which is then assigned to `p`, then the object goes out of scope on `;` and is destroyed, leaving `p` dangling.  Same with `p = &Particle(...);` with a *temporary* `Particle` object.

Comment: But if I store its address in a pointer, shouldn't C++ understand that I want to keep my reference to it?

Comment: No, that is not how C++ works. The temporary objects are being created in *automatic* memory storage, so they are destroyed when they go out of scope. For what you are attempting, you need to create the objects in *dynamic* memory storage instead

Comment: But if I do like @MooingDuck suggests: `particles.push_back(makeParticle(particle_type, particle_name, position, rotation, velocity, gravityEffect, lifeLength, scale));` why does that work? It is also creating a temporary object, right?

Comment: The only way that could work with polymorphic types is if `makeParticle()` creates the returned object *dynamically* via `new` (or `std::make_unique()`) and then returns a pointer (or `std::unique_ptr`) to the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213363/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-theforgot3n1).